# Voltage dropped significantly on GPIO 4 with a relay coil

Tags: gpio, relay, voltage

I have a Raspberry PI 3 B+, and when I activate the GPIO 4 as output and checking agains a multimeter I get its 3.3V as expected.

If I connect the GPIO4 to one end of a coil (http://www.electronicoscaldas.com/datasheet/JQC-3F-T73-Series_Liming.pdf) the voltage drops significantly, from 3.3V to 0.99V, and of course, the relay doesn't change it state.

I thought that the coil had a huge resistor and again checking with the multimeter I could verify that it has only 24Ω.

When using the pin 1 (3.3V continuosly) I see that the relay gets activated.

What's wrong with GPIO4? Is there another GPIO which I can replace this with?

Comment: `DO NOT` connect a GPIO directly to an inductive load like a relay coil or a motor.  You will destroy the GPIO and then the Pi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the GPIO, it just can't supply enough current for your coil.

If the coil has just 24Ω, at a 3,3V the GPIO would need to supply 137mA.

[This source at raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=142170) says that the maximum current it 51mA for all GPIOs together and 16mA per GPIO.

You can connect the GPIO to a transistor that can supply the necessary 137mA.

Answer (score 1):

@RalfFriedl is right, but I found some relays which are done for raspberry and arduino.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=My1BDB1ei0E

Now the circuit works.

@joan do you think that this kind of relay will destroy the board?

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

Why?

> (1) It does not work when GPIO4 connects to a relay switch/coil, but
>
> (2) It works when GPIO4 is connected to the input of another relay
>   module?

***Answer***

There is a big difference between a "relay switch/coil", and a "relay module".

> Case (1) GPIO4 is connected to directly a "relay coil", which needs
>   30mA to 70mA to switch on.  In
>
> Case (2) GPIO4 is connected to the input driver circuit (usually a
>   transistor or a optical isolated transistor) This input driver needs
>   only 3mA to 5mA to activate another power transistor which can output
>   30~70mA to drive the relay coil.  So there is no problem.

*In other words, you confuse between a "relay coil" and a "relay module" which consists of a input driver which indirectly drives a relay coil.*